# Error binding Combobox to Datatable WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, combobox

We are trying to get our combobox to bind to a Datatable. Out datatable consists of two columns "Kommune Navn" and "Kommune Nr" but for every row we are getting the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Kommune Nr' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=50916928)'. BindingExpression:Path=Kommune Nr; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=50916928); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

our combobox:

```
<ComboBox 

                DisplayMemberPath="Kommune Navn"
                SelectedValuePath="Kommune Nr"
                ItemsSource="{Binding KommuneNavne}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding kommuneNr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Margin="3"
                />
```

Our Viewmodel:

```
private DataTable _kommuneNavne;

public DataTable KommuneNavne
    {
        get { return _kommuneNavne; }
        set
        {
            _kommuneNavne = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(KommuneNavne));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like error related to `Path=Land.Navn;`. Could you post that XAML here as well ?

Comment: Sorry, it was actually the wrong errormessage i posted. This is the correct one System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Kommune Nr' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=56246151)'. BindingExpression:Path=Kommune Nr; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=56246151); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Comment: I've added the correct error now.

Comment: Column names should not contain spaces. I don't know if it will work, but try wrapping braces around the name like: `[Kommune Nr]`. Otherwise, create a Type to hold the data and bind to a collection of that Type instead of a DataTable.

Comment: I will try that tommorow when I have the opportunity again thank you :)